# What is profits of lazy directory iteration?

Tags: d, lazy-evaluation

I am reading Phobos docs and found method [dirEntries](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_file.html#.dirEntries) that complete "lazily iterates a given directory". But I can't understand real profits of it.

As I understand lazy function mean function that calculate only at time when it's needed.

Let's look at next code:

```
auto files = dirEntries(...);
auto cnt = files.count; 
foreach( file; files ) {  }
```

How much times `dirEntries` would be called? One or two? Please explain me the logic.

Or for example [splitter](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_iteration.html#splitter)

For me it's make code much more harder for understanding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lazy evaluation can be much more efficient if used correctly.

Say you have a somewhat expensive function that does something and you apply it to a whole range:

```
auto arr = iota(0, 100000); // a range of numbers from 0 to 100000
arr.map!(number => expensiveFunc(number))
   .take(5)
   .writeln;
```

If map wasn't lazy, it would execute `expensiveFunc` for all 100000 items in the range, and then pop off the first 5 of them.

But because map is lazy, expensiveFunc will only be called for the 5 items actually popped from the range.

Similarly with splitter, say you've a csv string with some data in it and you want to continue summing values until you meet a negative value.

```
string csvStr = "100,50,-1,1000,10,24,51"

int sum;
foreach(val; csvStr.splitter(",")){
    immutable asNumber = val.to!int;
    if(asNumber < 0) break;
    sum += asNumber;
}
writeln(sum);
```

The above will only do the expensive 'splitting' work 3 times, as splitter is lazy and we only had to read 3 items. Saving us from having to keep splitting csvStr until the end, even though we don't need them.

So, in summary, the profits of lazy evaluation are that only the work that **NEEDS** to be done is actually done.